# Good way to arrange variables and command calls in bash scripts

Tags: bash, coding-style

Is there some good way to graphically align the command calls in bash scripts when they're prefixed with a variable? I've got a script with a lot of lines that look like this

```
GIT_EDITOR="some interesting command with 'quoting and' spaces" "${SOME_DIR}/actual_command" argument
```

this doesn't look good and it's hard to find what the command really is when scanning the source quickly.

This seems to be a bit better, but still not perfect:

```
GIT_EDITOR="some interesting command with 'quoting and' spaces" \
    "${SOME_DIR}/actual_command" argument
```

Are there some more clear solutions?

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if this is any better than what you suggested, but:

```
env \
    GIT_EDITOR="some interesting command with 'quoting and' spaces" \
    "$SOME_DIR/actual_command" argument
```

Answer (score 1):

You could arrange this way:

```bsh
ShortVarName="some interesting command with 'quoting and' spaces"
GIT_EDITOR="$ShortVarName" "${SOME_DIR}/actual_command" argument
```

The idea is to keep the injected environment part as short as possible. If you name ShortVarName in a descriptive way, it will be readable too.

If you have lots of ShortVarName things, you could group them at the top of the file somewhere, so you can reference them quickly (using your search function?) if needed, but so they don't get in the way of the readability of the code where they are actually used.

If the GIT_EDITOR variable stays unchanged in your script, and it's OK to have it globally available, you may want to `export` it once at the beginning and not prepend it to commands at all.